# React Router v4 lazy loading with server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading, react-router-v4

I am using react router v4 with `bundle-loader` to split my code to chunks and make my components async.
Also I am using express for server side and now trying to use `StaticRouter` of react router to pre-render my react app.

this is my routes.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Bundle from 'shared/Bundle';
import LightApp from 'bundle-loader?lazy&name=lightApp!./LightApp';
import FinancialApp from 'bundle-loader?lazy&name=financialApp!./FinancialApp/index';

const bundler = (module) => (
    () => (
        <Bundle load={ module }>
            {
                (Comp) => Comp ? <Comp /> : <div>Loading</div>
            }
        </Bundle>
    )
);

const Routes = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ bundler(LightApp) } />
        <Route path='/(market|symbol)' component={ bundler(FinancialApp) } />
    </Switch>
);

export default Routes;
```

Where [`Bundle`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting) component is from react router official site.

and here is my server side script.

```
import express from 'express';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import configureStore from './src/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import InitialState from './src/reducers/initialState';
import StaticRouter from 'react-router-dom/StaticRouter';
import App from './src/components/App';
import config from './config';

let app = express();
let env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.locals.ENV = env;
app.locals.ENV_DEVELOPMENT = env == 'development';

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(logger('dev'));


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist', { maxAge: 86400000 * 7, lastModified: true }));

// handle app requests and server side rendering;
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    let  markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={}>
            <App />
        </StaticRouter>
    );

    res.render('index.ejs', {
        markup,
        state: {},
        assets: {
            bundle: assets['bundle'],
            vendor: assets['vendor'],
            styles: assets['styles']
        }
    });
})

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    res.json({
        message: app.locals.ENV_DEVELOPMENT ? err.message : 'Intrenal Server Error',
        error: err,
        title: 'error'
    });
});

app.listen(config.port, function () {
    console.log(`Finstead server listening on port ${ config.port }`);
});
```

But with webpack with `target: 'node'` I am getting splitted code files which should be only one `server.js` file instead of `0.server.js` `1.server.js` and so, because I need not code splitting on server side.

Also on my dev enviroment where I am using babel-watch for my server side I am getting this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bundle-loader?lazy&name=lightApp!./LightApp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\finstead\client\src\components\Routes.jsx:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at babelWatchLoader (D:\Projects\finstead\client\node_modules\babel-watch\runner.js:50:13)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .jsx] (D:\Projects\finstead\client\node_modules\babel-watch\runner.js:61:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

How to should I use lazy loading and server side rendering with react router v4?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi @shabenda, unfortunately this issue can't be fixed, because v4 can't handle this task. In docs I found text here (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting/code-splitting-server-rendering) which says that authors couldn't find best solution for handling this and they have dropped this, as well as said that Google can crawl content without server side render too, so it can't harm SEO, but I am not sure about other search engines :)))

Comment: I understand. It would be great.